# WPF Virtualizing Stack Panel - Look ahead?

Tags: wpf, virtualization, stackpanel

I was wondering if there is any way to control the WPF VirtualizingStackPanel look ahead items.
Meaning - i can see that when my list loads 10 items are visible but 20 items are being instantiated. 
So i assume 10 items are the look ahead of the stackpanel, and was wondering if i can control this.

In addition - does anyone know of a way to improve performance of VirtualizingStackPanel via parallelism? I want it to instantiate the items in parallel, of course since this is a ui thread it will probably fail - but maybe someone had made something similar before?...

Thanx Guys!
Gili